# RTC Memory ESP8266 12-E read an write

Tags: esp8266, arduino-esp8266, real-time-clock

What would be the right syntax for writing a variable lets say the int `100` into the RTC Memory of an ESP8266 12-E module and retrieve it after reboot or deep sleep.

Comment: maybe a better fit on: http://electronics.stackexchange.com ... I don't know of an RTC with separate addressable memory; so... I can't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the methods from the `ESP` class:

```
    bool rtcUserMemoryRead(uint32_t offset, uint32_t *data, size_t size);
    bool rtcUserMemoryWrite(uint32_t offset, uint32_t *data, size_t size);
```

There's an example in the ESP8266 Core for Arduino in [RTCUserMemory.ino](https://github.com/esp8266/Arduino/blob/master/libraries/esp8266/examples/RTCUserMemory/RTCUserMemory.ino).